# Can Xcode autocomplete header files / includes?

Tags: c++, xcode, autocomplete, include

I just had a simple question - Is it possible to get suggestive text when typing out an include?

Comment: Anyone?  I seem to recall seeing some YouTubers who were using Xcode with autocomplete, but I can't seem to recall what videos I was watching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it can. You have to have your `#include` in place, then have both `<` and `>` typed out, then, you'll get the auto complete list to pop up when typing between `<>`.  I never knew this.  I always assumed that after completing `#include <`, typing after would auto complete the header file name and the final `>`.

Short recap:

1) Type `#include`
2) Type both `<` and `>`
3) Insert cursor between `<>` and begin typing
4) Auto complete should now be working